# HAProxy on OPNSense

Tags: haproxy, opnsense

is it possible to use 1 Public IP for the Public Service that will be use by different sub domains with port 80 as its port.

```
    sub1.domain.com Real Server  172.16.100.20 Port 80
    sub2.domain.com Real Server  172.16.100.21 Port 80
    sub3.domain.com Real Server  172.16.100.22 Port 80
```

with the condition prefix base on the subdomain

Public Service has the public IP 443 and 80

I was actually trying this setup but it end up loading the same content on all subs.